How should I use JML to indicate that a java.util.function.Function object's apply method is pure?
First, I will state that I would just piddle around until I discovered a solution which works and is readable, but I am experiencing some pretty bizarre difficulties while trying to build OpenJML-0.21.0-alpha-0 on OpenBSD 7.5.  Anyway, I should probably get to the point.
I am currently working on a project which uses java.util.function.Function for the sake of customization.  The apply() methods of some of these Function objects should be pure, and I would like to be able to ensure that these methods actually are pure.
The JML Reference Manual describes the use of the pure statement for the description of functions, but no mentions of Function exist, and I have not seen anything which is terribly similar.
I suppose that creating a new PureFunction class is possible, but I wish to avoid this boilerplate if such avoidance is at all possible.
Using JML, how should I ensure that the methods are pure?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
